# Google container builder task cannot find gcloud

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, google-container-builder

I am using the vsts google container builder task inside my build pipeline.
I am running this task on a Hosted Linux preview vsts agent.

The container builder task fails to find gcloud on the agent machine.

 `##[error]Failed which: Not found gcloud: null`

I also tried installing gcloud on the agent using the  installer and adding gcloud to the PATH

`curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
source /root/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc`

Container builder tasks fails to find gcloud.
Is there something I am missing out ?

Comment: What's the "google container builder task" do you use? Can you provoder the task link or the screen shot for the task?

Comment: Are you using Cloud Build (https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/) formerly "Container Builder"? If so, what you probably (I don't understand your configuration) want to do is use the `gcloud` builder (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/gcloud) as a discrete step in your build pipeline rather than install gcloud in the agent.